# Replace numpy cell with values from second array based on a condition

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy

I have two images, `img1` and `img2`. I'm trying to find everywhere in `img1` that the color `[0,204,204]` occurs and replace it with whatever is in `img2` in the same place. I can  use `np.where()` to find the places where that color occurs and replace it with a different color directly:

```
img1[np.where((img1==[0,204,204]).all(axis=2))] = [255,255,0]
```

I'm unsure how to grab the indices of these cells as the shape of the images are 5070000 with 3 dimensions, so, I can't display the array's effectively. Looking over the numpy documentation, I think I can do something like:

```
img2[img1[img1==[0,204,204]]]
```

to get the indices of `img1` where that color occurs and then call the same array position from `img2`, but, I can't seem to get this syntax correct. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use the following:

```
img1[np.where((img1==[0,204,204]).all(axis=2))] = img2[np.where((img1==[0,204,204]).all(axis=2))]
```

This works because the syntax you had originally (`np.where((img1==[0,204,204]).all(axis=2))`) already returns the indices you are looking for

Example (on a small array):

```
img1 = np.array([[[0,204,204],[0,0,0],[1,2,3]]])

array([[[  0, 204, 204],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  1,   2,   3]]])

img2 = np.array([[[0,1,2],[1,1,1],[2,7,3]]])

array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [2, 7, 3]]])

img1[np.where((img1==[0,204,204]).all(axis=2))] = img2[np.where((img1==[0,204,204]).all(axis=2))]

>>> img1
array([[[0, 1, 2],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 3]]])
```

Comment: Works perfectly. It seems so obvious now. Thank you!